# How to use Authentication again after it was granted prevously

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

```
-(void)getGoogleCalendar{    
GTLServiceCalendar *calendarService = self.calendarService;    
GTLQueryCalendar *calendarListQuery = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForCalendarListList];
[calendarService executeQuery:calendarListQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLCalendarCalendarList * object, NSError *error) {       
    for (GTLCalendarCalendarListEntry *calendar in object.items) {
       [self getEventsForTheGivenCalendar:calendar.identifier];
    }        
    }];
}
```

For the First Time after the Login it works perfect but when  app starts after that it gives error

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Login Required)" UserInfo=0x79eb4f90
>   {error=Login Required, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x79fa9270:
>   {message:"Login Required" code:401 data:[1]},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Login Required)}

I am using `GTMOAuth2Authentication` authentication for the login and storing the user details. If the user details are not nil it doesn't ask for login and then the error occurs while fetching the calendar.

How to fetch GTLCalendar every time the app runs?

Comment: For your use case, better us offline access so that once app is authorized, you no need to authorize again. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092871/how-to-use-a-google-offline-access-token-to-authenticate-in-background-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

You should set the service authorizer in order to be able to make queries.

```
calendarService.authorizer = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:KEYCHAINITEMNAME
                                                                           clientID:CLIENTID
                                                                       clientSecret:CLIENTSECRET];
```