# GTMOAuth2Authentication problems with storing access token

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I have trouble using `[self isAuthorized]` to get confirmation of the access token I've got earlier.

Every time I'm login in with Google Drive SDK for iOS with:

```
// Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google Drive.
-(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)createAuthController {

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;
    authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scopes
                                                                clientID:kClientID
                                                            clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    return authController;
}
```

After the authentification completed, there is no error so the access token should be saved correctly

```
// Handle completion of the authorization process, and updates the Drive service
// with the new credentials.
-(void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil)
    {
        //[self showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
        self.driveService.authorizer = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.driveService.authorizer = authResult;
    }
}
```

I used an NSLog to make sure I received the access token and It did.

```
-(BOOL)isAuthorized {

    NSString *oauthToken = [((GTMOAuth2Authentication *)self.driveService.authorizer) accessToken];
    NSLog(@"oauthToken: %@", oauthToken);


    return [((GTMOAuth2Authentication *)self.driveService.authorizer) canAuthorize];
}
```

But When I look if I'm authorized or not, there is no token saved (oauthToken is NULL) and I need to login again.

N.B: It was working in the past before iOS 9. I don't know if it is related.

Thanks
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like [this](https://github.com/googledrive/ios-quickeditor/blob/master/ios-quickeditor/ios-quickeditor/QEFilesListViewController.m) to verify login:

```
// Check for authorization.
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth =
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                      clientID:kClientId
                                                  clientSecret:kClientSecret];
if ([auth canAuthorize]) {
    [self isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:auth];
}
```

On the other hand, if you really want the access token, check out this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092871/how-to-use-a-google-offline-access-token-to-authenticate-in-background-on-ios), however, it is not best practice to store the access token, since access token has an expiration time. Good luck & Hope this helps.