# gmail api full email access given the message id of email

Tags: ios, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying to access the gmail messages in offline access mode. gmail access token I get from the server end.

I followed this link to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092871/how-to-use-a-google-offline-access-token-to-authenticate-in-background-on-ios/23273833#23273833)
I created my own authenticator class  and subclass from GTMOAuth2Authentication and implemented the protocol as mentioned in the above link.

The canAutherize always fail and even though I make gmail query, It crashes in authorize function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self.subjectInfo length] > 0) {
        [self.subjectLabel setText:self.subjectInfo];
    }else {
        [self.subjectLabel setText:@""];
    }

    self.service = [[GTLServiceGmail alloc] init];

    [self fetchAccessToken];

    // Initialize the Gmail API service & load existing credentials from the keychain if available.

}

    // When the view appears, ensure that the Gmail API service is authorized, and perform API calls.
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        if (!self.service.authorizer.canAuthorize) {
            // Not yet authorized, request authorization by pushing the login UI onto the UI stack.
    //        [self presentViewController:[self createAuthController] animated:YES completion:nil];
            [self fetchAccessToken];

        } else {
            [self fetchMail:[self gmailMsgId]];
        }
    }




    -(void) fetchAccessToken
    {
        [[APIManager sharedManager] fetchGmailToken:^(NSDictionary *resultDict) {
            if (resultDict != nil) {
                self.accessToken = [resultDict objectForKey:@"access_token"];
                _authInst = [[GmailAuthenticator alloc] initWithAccessToken:self.accessToken];
                self.service.authorizer = _authInst;
        }


        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"fail to fetch access token");
        }];
    }



    - (void)fetchMail:(NSString*)messageId {

        GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesGet];
        query.messageId = messageId;

        [self.service executeQuery:query
                          delegate:self
                 didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
    }



    - (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
                 finishedWithObject:(GTLGmailMessage *)messageResponse
                              error:(NSError *)error {
        if (error == nil) {

            NSLog(@"description is %@", [messageResponse description]);
        } else {

             NSLog(@"error : %@", [error description]);
        }
    }
```